# Finding an inversion score using R

Tags: r

Sorry in advance if "inversion score" isn't the proper terminology. Here's a [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_%28discrete_mathematics%29) entry.

Consider a list of values, for instance

```
1 2 3 4 7 6 9 10 8
```

would have three penalties (a score of 3)

- The 6 comes after 7
- The 8 comes after 9
- The 8 comes after 10

How can I calculate this inversion for a given vector of numbers in R? Note that some values will be NA, and I just want to skip these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly came up with two strategies. A naive and a more clever using the `outer` function.

We look at two vectors of numbers `A` and `B`, where `A` is your example.

```
A <- scan(text = "1 2 3 4 7 6 9 10 8")
B <- sample(1:2321)
```

Define and try the naive inversion counting:

```
simpleInversion <- function(A) {
  sum <- 0
  n <- length(A)
  for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):n) {
      sum <- sum + (A[i] > A[j])
    }
  }
  return(sum)
}

simpleInversion(A)
simpleInversion(B)
```

Define and try the slightly more clever inversion counting:

```
cleverInversion <- function(A) {
  tab <- outer(A, A, FUN = ">")
  return(sum(tab[upper.tri(tab)]))
}

cleverInversion(A)
cleverInversion(B)
```

For the version which ignores NAs we can simply add an `na.omit`:

```
cleverInversion2 <- function(A) {
  AA <- na.omit(A)
  Tab <- outer(AA, AA, FUN = ">")
  return(sum(Tab[upper.tri(Tab)]))
}

A[2] <- NA
cleverInversion2(A)
```

Hope this helps.

### Edit: A faster version

Both functions become quite slow quickly when the size of the vector grows. So I came up with at faster version:

```
fastInversion <- function(A) {
  return(sum(cbind(1, -1) %*% combn(na.omit(AA), 2) > 0))
}

C <- sample(c(1:500, NA))
library("microbenchmark")
microbenchmark(
  simpleInversion(C),
  cleverInversion(C),
  fastInversion(C))
#Unit: microseconds
#               expr        min         lq     median         uq        max neval
# simpleInversion(C) 128538.770 130483.626 133999.272 144660.116 185767.208   100
# cleverInversion(C)   9546.897   9893.358  10513.799  12564.298  17041.789   100
#   fastInversion(C)    104.632    114.229    193.144    198.209    324.614   100
```

So we gain quite a speed-up of nearly two orders of magnitude. The speed-up is even greater for larger vectors.

Answer (score 5):

Your "inversion score" is a central component of [Kendall's tau statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient).  According to Wikipedia (see link), the tau statistic is `(# concordant pairs-#discordant pairs)/(n*(n-1)/2)`.  I *believe* that what R reports as `T` is the number of concordant pairs. Therefore, we should be able to reconstruct the number of discordant pairs (which I think is what you want) via `n*(n-1)/2-T`, as follows

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,7,6,9,10,8)
(cc <- cor.test(sort(x),x,method="kendall"))

##  Kendall's rank correlation tau
## data:  sort(x) and x
## T = 33, p-value = 0.0008543
## alternative hypothesis: true tau is not equal to 0
## sample estimates:
##       tau 
## 0.8333333
```

So this function should work:

```
ff <- function(x) {
    cc <- cor.test(sort(x),x,method="kendall")
    n <- length(x)
    n*(n-1)/2-unname(cc$statistic["T"])
}
```

`ff(x)` is 3 as requested (it would be good if you gave more examples of desired output ...) Haven't checked speed, but this has the advantage of being implemented in underlying C code.

Comment: You may want `unname(n*(n-1)/2-cc$statistic["T"])` as the last line of `ff`, for clarity of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You could test each pair of values in your vector, counting the number that are inverted:

```
inversion.score <- function(vec) {
  sum(apply(combn(length(vec), 2), 2, function(x) vec[x[2]] < vec[x[1]]), na.rm=T)
}
inversion.score(c(1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 9, 10, 8, NA))
# [1] 3
```